# How to fix java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING in cmd windows Gson, Apache Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, gson

I have this piece of code:

```
File jsonFile = Paths.get(jsonPath).toFile();
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(jsonFile));

Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<Pattern>>(){}.getType();
List<Pattern> listPatterns = new Gson().fromJson(bufferedReader, collectionType);
```

when I run it on IntelliJ, it got successfull but after building to jar file, and running by Spark-submit in windows CMD it got Error:

```
spark-submit --class com.bigdata.main.Application --master local[1] target\extraction.jar
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:815)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
        at com.bigdata.main.Application.main(Application.java:42)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:849)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:338)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:79)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
        ... 14 more
```

my json file run OK in IntelliJ and Centos linux command, but it got error when run on Windows.

Json contents:

```
[
   {
      "bankName": "Bank1",
      "Patterns": [
         {
            "category": "daily",
            "type": "",
            "pattern": "pattern_regex_1"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "bankName": "Bank2",
      "Patterns": [
         {
            "category": "daily",
            "type": "",
            "pattern": "pattern_regex_2"
         },
         {
            "category": "daily",
            "type": "",
            "pattern": "pattern_regex_3"
         },
         {
            "category": "visa",
            "type": "",
            "pattern": "pattern_regex_4"
         },
         {
            "category": "visa",
            "type": "",
            "pattern": "pattern_regex_5"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Thank you for your supports!

Comment: can you provide content of the JSON file?

Comment: @vatsalmevada I have edited the content of JSON file, thank you!

Comment: Can you read the content of the file in a string and log it.Make sure that content of the file is small enough to avoid OOM. This code might be helpful: `String text = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("file")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Comment: Why is this question tagged Powershell, I see zero reference to it in the actual post?

Comment: @PMental I had mistake, edited, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mr @vatsalmevada because he gave me correct anwser!

use:

```
String text = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("file")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

to convert the

Comment: hey that was not the answer. It was just a debug step. Reading the entire file in memory is not practical. What if your input file size is in GBs? It will lead to out of memory errors. Please print the text read using the code I have given and add the output to the post. Is it the same as the content of the file?